# Content Restriction but allow public REST API

Tags: conditional-content, post-content, content-restriction, posting

My Question, is it possible to restrict the content from a post (shwo e.g. teaser/excerpt only) but still let access the content fully by the REST Api interface?

My scenario is that i would like to force my page viewer to my app, where the content is showing via rest api fully.

I tried couple content restriction plugins like content control, but all of the also restrict the access via REST Api.

Thanks for any hints on this.

Comment: You can check to see if the constant `REST_REQUEST` is defined (and `true`) to determine if you're in a REST request, and then *not* apply your content lockdown filter(s) there. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52512562/1094518) (and note that `REST_REQUEST` will be defined after the `wp` hook has fired, but it's not available yet on the `init` hook).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems like it goes in the right direction. Do you have an example hook for this? I would prefer to use an exsiting content restriction plugin and exclude the function only for the WP-Request. Is it possible in this way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `REST_REQUEST` constant to detect if this is a REST request, and if it's not, apply your filter(s).

Example:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse418531_use_excerpt' );
/**
 * Replaces the content with the excerpt, unless this is a REST request.
 *
 * @param  string $content The post content.
 * @return string          The filtered post content.
 */
function wpse418531_use_excerpt( $content ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        // If this is an admin page, returns the content unchanged.
        return $content;
    }
    if ( defined( REST_REQUEST ) && true === REST_REQUEST ) {
        // If this is a REST request, returns the content unchanged.
        return $content;
    }
    $content = get_the_excerpt();

    // If you want to add a note about your app, you can do it here.
    // If not, delete these lines.
    $content .= '<p>See more on <a href="https://example.com/download/my/app/">my app</a>.</p>';

    return $content;
}
```

**Note:** This code is *untested*. Don't use it on a production site till you've ensured it works properly. It's also meant as a starting point for you, not a finished product.

### References

- [`rest_api_loaded()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_api_loaded/) which contains `REST_REQUEST` (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52512562/1094518) for the info)
- [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/)
- [`get_the_excerpt()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why, but the get_the_excerpt() function not work for me. The if-clause for checking if it's a rest api request or not also not work as needed, i add a new function for that check. I take some adjustment for the excerpt part and it is working for me know as i needed. I limit the content to 55 words and for the rest api it provides the full content.

Pat J thanks for your help and pushing me to the right direction. Here is my working code:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse418531_use_excerpt' );
function is_rest() {
    return ( defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) && REST_REQUEST );
}
function wpse418531_use_excerpt( $content ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        // If this is an admin page, returns the content unchanged.
        return $content;
    }
    if ( is_rest() ) {
        // If this is a REST request, returns the content unchanged.;
        return $content;
    }
    $content = wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 55);
    $content .= 'Continue via App';
    $content .= '<p><a href="https://example.org">AppStore</a> | <a href="https://example.org">PlayStore</a></p>';

    return $content;
}
```